# Typescript - how to define types nested object with dynamic keys

Tags: typescript

How can I define types for following situation? I'm writing translations files, and I need to be able to create object in that shape:

```
const messages = {
  key: ['str', 'str'],
  key2: ['str', 'str'],
  key3: {
    innerKey: ['str', 'str'],
    innerKey2: ['str', 'str'],
    ...
  },
  key4: ['str', 'str'],
  ...
}
```

I'm sharing a code snippet with my tries:

```
type Message = string[];

type Messages = {
  [key: string]: { [key: string]: Message } | Message;
};

// only one level of nesting
// every key can be dynamic
const userMessages: Messages = {
  parts: {
    first_name: ['user>>parts>>first_name', 'Name'],
    last_name: ['user>>parts>>last_name', 'Surname'],
  },
  user: ['user>>user', 'User'],
};

console.log(userMessages.parts.first_name)
console.log(userMessages.parts.last_name)


// Property 'first_name' does not exist on type 'Message | { [key: // string]: Message; }'.
// Property 'first_name' does not exist on type 'Message'.
// Property 'last_name' does not exist on type 'Message | { [key: string]: Message; }'.
// Property 'last_name' does not exist on type 'Message'.
```

on TS playground:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAshDO8CGBzaBeK9gCcCWAdigNoC6A3ALABQNoksCya8UmA3jVFMQNYQgAXFlyEUpYex78hI-EQmNEqaAF8oAHyXMIVaqr00A9EagB7AgBsQ5gtEsQAbhEvmAZlDvYxx004g4NjJQAMZIBFAARtAAJiAESAC2eCE0IRbYUACu8AFwyizC+TqsHFxQYEg4wPCS5dxueDjYAPoJiRDCxADkOQEAfP2V1fCDjc3AbUkQ3QA0UN0ActPdpLP1UJZIre2dPL25OIPDNYNbOyvz3QDKWTi7q+vU3KpP3H04XQcD-R9zCwBVQ6PGgGGhpDJmBwAOksZhQAAoPsUVPBoSc0eMLh0AJQQgjwKEQWHwpGHFEsdFVGqw7aTXZ46hAA

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You are far more likely to get a response if you can post your snippets (or even small relevant portions of them) directly in your question. Many users don't like to, and won't, click on links for a variety of valid reasons.

Comment: It's because each type in union type needs the same property when accessing it. Even if it's undefined or dynamic key. You have to explicit tell a type that dynamic keys. For example `string[] & Record<string, any>` (Record is basically the same as `{[key: string]: something}` see [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type). ... TypeScript needs a feature to allow implicit dynamic undefined keys on uinion type. Here is an issue of it: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1260 Also see https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12815.

Comment: ... You could just cast or check key is in object. Like `console.log('first_name' in userMessages.parts ? userMessages.parts.first_name : undefined);` or `console.log((userMessages.parts as Record<string, Message>).last_name);` But you can't access a key which lacks on one type.